# Typescript getter/setter naming convention

Tags: angular, typescript, naming-conventions

I come from a Java background and I defaulted to using getter/setter naming conventions in my Typescript/Angular component classes familiar to me.

```
getFoo()

setFoo()
```

However, it seems that this may not be the best practice, but rather I should use the convention

```
get foo()

set foo()
```

Questions

- Is this purely cosmetic? Any benefits?  I don't understand why this would be favored since it is, to my understanding, inconsistent with the naming convention used for other methods.
- Is there a formal style guide recommending this practice?

Comment: Those are not the same. `getFoo` is just a regular function. In `get foo`, `get` is a reserved keyword for a getter. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `get`, `set` where we need to implement some constraints when a value is accessed.

From Typescript documentation:

> TypeScript supports getters/setters as a way of intercepting accesses
>   to a member of an object. This gives you a way of having finer-grained
>   control over how a member is accessed on each object.

Example:

```
class StudentMark {
    isPass: boolean;
    _mark: Mark;
    set mark(value: Mark) {
        if (value.subject1 > 35 && value.subject2 > 35&& value.subject3 > 35) { 
             this.isPass = true;
        } else {
             this.isPass = false;
        }
        this._mark = value;
    }
   get mark(): Mark {
       return this._mark;
   }
}
```

Here, whenever we set the mark, the pass will be updated. No, need to update it separately. In this, type of cases get, set will be useful.

Suffix of get and set should have same name. And we can access it by only calling the name itself. Example, `mark` from above code.

For, more about get, set visit typescript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors).

Comment: This won't pass typescript strict compilation mode; `_mark: Mark` should be `_mark?: Mark` and `get mark()` should check if `_mark` is set before returning, or be declared `: Mark | undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

type-script is superset of java-script and all of language syntax very similar of [ECMAScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) standard because programmer feeling better writing java-script application.

SET, GET property on TS & JS very similar

JS

```
class JSExample {
    constructor() {
        this._val = "V";
    }
    get val() {
        return this._val;
    }
    set val($v) {
        this._val = $v;
    }
}
```

TS

```
class TSExample {
    _val = "V";

    get val(): string {
        return this._val;
    }
    set val($v: string) {
        this._val = $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. For what reason do you use the $ sign with a variable name? According to 
 the Google TypeScript Style Guide in the Getters and Setters (Accessors) section it is not needed.
The quote from the guide: [Google Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/tsguide.html)
</br>
set someMember(newValue: string) { ... }

Comment: $ character is not special in javascript is similar other standard naming convention character.

But when we use the set property, the JS language assigns a value to the setter, so I think it uses the $ character.

Using Style Guide should not limit your mind because programming language is not limited to anything